# Azure Data Factory - Error ingesting data from MySql or Blob Storage

Tags: mysql, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Since last week we're facing some issues involving Data Factory Copy Activities. The issue occurs when the data is already staged into the Blob Storage and it starts to be copied into the SQL DW.

What we can see is that the Throughput rate decreases till we get the following message error:

*{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectToSqlServer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server: 'despesas.database.windows.net', Database: 'csc', User: 'master'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.),Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=121,Class=20,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=20,Number=121,State=0,Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.),},],''Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=The semaphore timeout period has expired,Source=,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy Data1"*

Notice that the issue started last week!

Comment: I just checked some details and the resources are in the same region. When I tried to run the activity having SQL DW as source and destination, as well as my Blob Storage as staging area, it fails also from the source to the blob, which means that the issue is between the SQL DW and my Blob Storage, as the communication doesn't use any Integration Runtime resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an Azure Integration Runtime in the same region of the SQL database, sometimes the auto detect region doesnt work.

Create an Azure IR in that region, and create the linked service again, using the new Integration Runtime.

That should solve your problem.

Hope this helped!